# Streams via Socket

Tags: java, sockets, exception, stream

I am writing server-client application. Client sends some sort of data via different streams to the server. Once I place streams like this in the main method the program does nothing; no exception just empty console:

```
try {
                socket = new Socket("localhost", 4050);                     
                din = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                oin = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                dout = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());                     


            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {              
                System.out.println("Exception: the host is unknown");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("I/O exception thrown by socket");
            }
```

Once I remove this stream  `oin = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());` from that part of  main method the program throws EOFException or connection reset exception.
What is so special in the above code that the program does nothing and throws no exceptions?

Once you place the mentioned stream in to a separate method

```
private static MessageObject readObject(){
        MessageObject mo = null;

        try{
             oin = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
             mo = (MessageObject)oin.readObject();

        } 
        catch(IOException e){
            System.err.println(e.getCause());
        }
        catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
            System.err.println(e.getCause());
        }
        return mo;
    }
```

It throws this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.DataInputStream.readBoolean(Unknown Source)
    at Server.main(Server.java:77)
```

On the server it is on the if branch:

```
if (din.readBoolean()) {

        ObjectInputStream oin = new ObjectInputStream(s.getInputStream());
        MessageObject o = (MessageObject)oin.readObject();

        // server saves the whole thing
        MessageDB.add(o);

    }
```

I can't place here all  my code, it is my assignment.

ooops, sorry people, the mistake has been found. Some logical mistake, the server was expecting some input,but the client was refusing to send it.

Comment: where exactly you're getting `EOFException`? looks like you're not showing the entire code

Comment: Well, there's no errors in that code...So that explains why nothing is happening with this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are making several mistakes here.

1. You are using multiple streams over the same socket. Don't do that, they will only confuse each other. As you need object I/O, just use an `ObjectInputStream` and `ObjectOutputStream` for everything.
2. Incorrect construction order. You must construct the `ObjectOutputStream` *before* the `ObjectInputStream`, at both ends.
3. You are using streams with different lifetimes. You haven't hit the problem yet but eventually this will lead to a `StreamCorruptedException`. Use the same `ObjectInputStream` and `ObjectOutputStream` for the life of the Socket, at both ends.
4. You probably also need to read the Javadoc for `ObjectOutputStream.reset()` and `.writeUnshared()` to understand what they do, and why you might need to call one or the other of them.